# Amperage for Fat PS2 with IEC C13 Female Lead Plug To UK 3 Pin Plug?

Tags: psn, backwards-compatibility, playstation-plus, ps2

Was trying to find the amperage for a FAT PS2 using a IEC C13 Female Lead Plug To UK 3 Pin Plug.
Can't seem to find the information anywhere.

Comment: Seems more like an engineering/hardware question as it's not about games at all, only about a gaming console.

Comment: I _think_ it may be related to some sort of part of a Playstation 2, but it's unclear if that is what the OP is asking about.  "FAT PS2" I think would be the original PS2 model first released (where the "slim" model came out later).

Comment: @l3l_aze "Game-specific hardware and utilities" are [explicitly on-topic](/help/on-topic)

Comment: pppery - Thank you for the correction; I even read that before commenting..lol. @Timmy Jim - Yes, it's the power cord of an original PS2, but it sounds like they're trying to plug in a USA version over the pond and worried about destroying the device in the process.